# Translation of perfect set still perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $P\subset\mathbb R$ be a perfect set. For each nonzero $r\in\mathbb R$,  define $$ D_r=r\cdot P$$ Without checking the details $D_r$ still perfect set. I think, it is true. Does that correct ?

Comment: Note that this is not a translation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I might use the word in the wrong way. Thank you for correction

Comment: That’s okay. Just so that you know, a translation of $P$ would be a set of the form $P+r$ for some $r\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, your comments and your answers help me a lot. By the way, Did you see my last comments about your construction in my question which is "pairwise disjoint dense set in the complement of meager set".

Comment: I know that they’re there and have a tab open to look at them when I have a little more free time.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Not that I have a stake in this, but would the correct terminology for the map be a dilation?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x \to rx$ is a homeomorphism so it certainly maps perfect sets to perfect sets.